# Does every positive Lebesgue measure set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contain a product of positive Lebesgue measure sets up to a null set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Let $P\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a positive Lebesgue measure set. Then $P$ may not contain a subset of the form $A\times B$ where $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$ are of positive Lebesgue measure.

For example consider $P=\{(x,y)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]:x-y\notin \mathbb{Q}\}.$

This example leads me to ask:

Given any $P\subset \mathbb{R}^2,$ a positive Lebesgue measure set, does there exists a measure zero set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $P\cup U$ contains a subset of the form $A\times B$ where $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}$ are of positive Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Related [A set of positive measure contains a product set of positive measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149968/152568)

Comment: How about the product of fat Cantor sets rotated by $45$ degrees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in general this is not true. Denote by $\lambda^d$ Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

It is possible to construct a Borel set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with strictly positive Lebesgue measure such that $\lambda^2(A^c \cap R)>0$ for any non-degenerate rectangle $R$, i.e. for any $R = S \times T$ where $S,T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ have positive Lebesgue measure;  the idea is to define

$$A:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\:;\: x-y \in B\}$$

for $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\lambda^1(B \cap I)>0$ and  $\lambda^1(B^c \cap I)>0$ for any interval $I \neq \emptyset$. See [1] for a proof that this set does the job. In particular, if $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is any Lebesgue null set, then $A \cup N$ still does not contain any rectangle $R$ since

$$\lambda^2((A \cup N)^c \cap R) = \lambda^2(A^c \cap R)>0.$$

[1] Darst, R. and Goffman, C.: A Borel Set which Contains no Rectangles. *The American
Mathematical Monthly* 77 (1970) 728–729.

Comment: Is $\lambda^m$ Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^m?$

Comment: @Mathemajician Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It was immensely helpful.