# A fat Cantor set essentially containing a positive measure subset and uncountably many of its translates

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

Edit: In writing out more details, I realized I needed to make a slight modification to the question. I switched all proper containments from the old version of the question to "essential containment".

This question arises in looking for a counterexample to a claim made in the book by Dunford and Schwartz, but seems interesting in its own right. The question I really want to answer is: "Does there exist a Lebesgue measurable set $C \subseteq [0,1]$ with $m(C)>0$ s.t. for every Lebesgue measurable $m(S \cap C^c) = 0$ s.t. $m(S) >0$, the set $\{x : m((x+S) \cap C^c) =0\}$ is Lebesgue null?"

It would suffice to show the following claim which seems possibly true:
"Let $C$ a fat Cantor set. Then for every $S \subseteq C$ s.t. $m(S)>0$, the set $\{x : m((x +S) \cap C^c)=0\}$ is countable."

Edit: Due to a request in the comments, I'll post a simplification of the claim made in Dunford and Schwartz that inspired the question. Let $(A, \mathcal{A},\alpha), (B, \mathcal{B},\beta)$ $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $(A \times B, \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}, \alpha \times \beta)$ their product. Let $f : A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$ measurable. Then there exists a sequence $\phi_n$ of finite linear combinations of indicators on measurable rectangles (sets of the form $S \times T, S \in \mathcal{A}, T \in \mathcal{B}$) s.t. $\phi_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. and $|\phi_n| \leq |f|$.

If we have a set $C$ of the above type, let $D := \{(x,x) + (c,0) : c \in C, 0 \leq x \leq 1\}.$ Then the above property shows that if $\phi$ is a finite linear combination of indicators of measurable rectangles s.t. $|\phi| \leq 1_D$, then $\phi = 0$ a.e. This contradicts the Dunford and Schwartz claim as we can show that $m(D)>0$.

Comment: @DonThousand Both claims, or just the one about the Cantor set? Could you provide justification, if you have it?

Comment: @DonThousand I may be missing something obvious, but I don't immediately see how the linked post resolves the above question.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the original claim (or point me to where it is in the book), assuming it's not just "there is no Lebesgue measurable set that does this thing"

Comment: @MichaelJesurum The claim above is pretty far from the original claim in Dunford and Schwartz. I tried to sketch the motivation in an edit.

Comment: Doesn't the following show that the claim in the book is false? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149968/a-set-of-positive-measure-contains-a-product-set-of-positive-measure See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42748/measurable-rectangles-inside-a-non-null-set and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3845826/does-every-positive-lebesgue-measure-set-in-mathbbr2-contain-a-product-of

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, it does. Thanks. The actual posted question is still interesting IMO, but that does resolve the motivating problem.